# MySQLi connection times out with two sequential SELECTs

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to use PHP to get results from database in an array structure. For that, I’m using the following code:

**config.php**:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "databasename");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

**database.class.php**:

```
class database
    {
        function __construct($mysqli)
        {
            $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
        }


        /*
         * Utility function to automatically bind columns from selects in prepared statements to
         * an array
         */
        function bind_result_array($stmt)
        {
            $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
            $result = array();
            while ($field = $meta->fetch_field())
            {
                $result[$field->name] = NULL;
                $params[] = &$result[$field->name];
            }

            call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);

            return $result;

        }

        /**
         * Returns a copy of an array of references
         */
        function getCopy($row)
        {
            return array_map(create_function('$a', 'return $a;'), $row);
        }

        function select($campos, $tabela, $condicao='')
        {
            $query = 'SELECT '.$campos.' FROM '.$tabela;
            if(trim($condicao!='')){
                $query.=' WHERE '.$condicao;
            }
            $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();
            $row = $this->bind_result_array($stmt);
            if(!$stmt->error)
            {
                while($stmt->fetch())
                    $dados[] = $this->getCopy($row);
            }

            return $dados;
        }
```

And to use this, I do the following:

```
$data = $db->select('*', 'users', 'idlevel = 1 LIMIT 10');
```

This `$data` will return me an array, like this one:

```
 [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(17)
    ["nome"]=>
    string(13) "Gareth Barlow"
    ["email"]=>
    string(30) "sit.amet@semPellentesqueut.net"
    ["idnivel"]=>
    int(1)
    ["password"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["departamento"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(20)
    ["nome"]=>
    string(9) "John Lara"
    ["email"]=>
    string(13) "odio@arcu.net"
    ["idnivel"]=>
    int(1)
    ["password"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["departamento"]=>
    NULL
  }
```

But, if I do another database call right after the line `$data"` like:

```
$foo = $db->select('*', 'users', 'idlevel = 2 LIMIT 10');
```

The browser tries to return the data, but in short time, it gives me “The connection was reset (...)”.

There is any way to execute those queries and return two arrays like this one?

---

### **UPDATE 1**

Okay, i think i found a solution for this one.

```
function select($campos, $tabela, $condicao='')
        {
            $query = 'SELECT '.$campos.' FROM '.$tabela;
            if(trim($condicao!='')){
                $query.=' WHERE '.$condicao;
            }
            $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);
            if ($result = $this->mysqli->query($query)) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $dados[] = $this->getCopy($row);
                }
                return $dados;
                $result->free();
            }
        }
```

This allows me to use to do the same thing, without error.
Thanks people ;)

Comment: This is probably unrelated to your problem, but this line: `if(trim($condicao!='')){` doesn't make sense. `$condicao!=''` is a boolean value (`true` or `false`), so you're trimming `true` or `false`. I think you mean `if(trim($condicao)!=''){`

Comment: yup, you're right Kryten. I only do this to check if there is any condition, else i execute the query anyway. that was a distraction of mine :D Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to close the statement object...

In the select function, before the

```
return $dados;
```

make a

```
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: I think that something is leaving open and in use from the first query... so when the second is executed, the database lock the query until "something" is released. Try making a $this->mysqli->commit() or $this->mysqli->rollback() between the first $db->select and the second...

Answer (score 0):

How about simply using different objects?

```
$db1 = new Database($mysqli);
$data1 = $db->select('*', 'users', 'idlevel = 1 LIMIT 10');

$db2 = new Database($mysqli);
$data2 = $db->select('*', 'users', 'idlevel = 1 LIMIT 10');

class Post extends Eloquent {
```

It doesn't solve the underlying problem in the database class, but it should buy you time to find an alternative.  To be honest, the one you're using doesn't look very useful.

Comment: that doesn't work to. you're right Dave, this solution is not the best one. But this was what i found to create this type of arrays... do you have any solution to create an array like this, with a different code ?